# Routing users to webroot subfolder in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I would like the / of a website to go to a sub folder in webroot like /app/webroot/frontend/ and everything /admin to the standard controllers and actions of cakephp.

The reason for this is, I have a standard html page as front end which gets data using ajax from cakephp that is located in the root. I do not want to use a redirect so that when users go to the site they are redirected to /app/webroot/frontend (seeing this in the URL). The admin is now accessible through /

Or is it wise to move the whole cakephp app to a sub folder admin and have the site run in the root / ?

Comment: The wise thing to do would be to include that HTML stuff in Cake, refactoring it as part of a CakePHP app (controller+action or just Pages page - and use some routing on top maybe), and not trying to hack around it. Having a single and complete CakePHP app, so that you leverage the framework instead of fighting it.

Comment: OK, that's clear. But how do I get the rest to act like the root is /admin ?

Comment: Why would /admin ever be the root? / is the root, whereas /admin is a subroot you can point to any action you want to.

Comment: Hi Mark, Like we have a controller called categories, activities and so on and I would want all controllers to be accessed with /admin in front of it, except the controller like Newton suggested. I now have the frontend index.html as a layout and use that in MainController. So everything except /main should get a URL /admin/controllername. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are confusing quite a few things here. Use "admin" routing instead. See the docs for details.

Comment: But Mark, for that I need to change all action names to admin_ :(

Comment: Not necessarily. Routing can do a lot for you. But you may rename them it you like. Either way, use a complete cake app and it will be less troublesome from here on forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot route directly from routes config, because this is designed to work with MVC.

Todo that with clear MVC code, follow the steps bellow.

Create a MainController at /Controller/MainController with

```
<?php
class MainController extends AppController {
    public function index(){
        $this->redirect('/frontend/index.html');
    }
}
?>
```

Change /Config/route.php, locate the default route rule and replace with:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'main', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Than, enjoy!

Comment: It's a good fix, only too bad that users will see a /frontend in the address bar

Comment: I now combined your answer with what Mark suggested. Just want all other controllers except /main to be accessed with a /admin in front of it. Any suggestions here?

Comment: So, you can simple create /View/Main/index.ctp and place the contents of index.html to that view.

This way, when access your site, the content displayed will be that, without any thing in URL like an index page in common http servers.